# Kubernetes API Budget Burn Errors

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, amazon-eks

I am confused about this metric and alert

```
sum(apiserver_request:burnrate3d) > (1 * 0.01) and sum(apiserver_request:burnrate6h) > (1 * 0.01)
```

I cannot find the source of the metrics `apiserver_request` and how it relates to an error. Right now we have 1 of four eks clusters firing this alert even the `apiserver_request:burnrate5m` shows a value greater than 0.01
We are running k8s `1.16` on eks and prom-operator deployed via helm chart version `9.3.1`

How do you find the source of metrics and what causes them for k8s

Comment: Do you have access to the Prometheus web interface? There you can see all defined rules and therefore derive the exact metric names that are used within a recording rule

Comment: Have you seen this -> https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/9698#issuecomment-680068851